# bash: how to sort or parse an array[id][name] by name alphabetic to inject into whiptail?

Tags: bash, whiptail

Full script is available on [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/mickro/steam-lr/blob/master/steam-lr)

When started with `steam-lr -g menu` it is showing menu made with `whiptail`. Items in this menu are ordered by `game id`.

*My question: is there a way to order them by `game name` ?*

**how items are generated:**

```
function build_gamemenu {
  i=0
  for f in ~/.steam/steam/steamapps/*.acf; do
    game_name=$(cat $f | grep \"name\" | sed 's/.*"name"\s*//;s/"//;s/"//')
    game_id=$(cat $f | grep \"appid\" | sed 's/.*"appid"//;s/"//;s/"//;s/^[ \t]*//')
    gamemenu[i]="$game_id"
    gamemenu[i+1]="$game_name"
    ((i+=2))
  done
}
```

- file names from listed folder look like `manifest_GAME_ID.acf` *(ie: manifest_1234.acf)*
- `$game_id` is always a number
- `$game_name` may contain space and special characters

**how items are passed to whiptail:**

```
function menu {
# (...)
game_id=$(whiptail --notags --backtitle "$version" --title "SteamLR" --menu "Select a game:" $w_h $w_w $w_l "${gamemenu[@]}" 2>&1 >/dev/tty)
# (...)
}
```

- `${gamemenu[@]}` generates properly a computed string of `$game_id "$game_name"`. And as far it is the only way I found.

Comment: @charles array[id][name] does work in bash... may this following piece of batch convince you: `b[43]=plip;b[99]=plop;echo ${b[43]};echo ${b[99]}` ? Else you are true, the main question is a bit confused.

Comment: Uhh, that's `array[id]`, not `array[id][name]`. The part I'm asserting doesn't work / isn't possible is nesting arrays inside arrays.

Comment: oh yes I m wrong again

Comment: So, I'd like to propose that this be retitled to "How can I sort a list of key/value pairs by key in bash?" -- that's a more general / widely-applicable question (which stays focused on a single concern, vs pulling in unrelated content about whiptail / file parsing / etc), and I'm not finding a good near-duplicate. We have people who want to sort *by value*, or want to maintain original insertion order, but those are distinct questions.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't use numeric indexes for your array; instead, use the actual name.**

That way you can sort your names out-of-band and iterate over the sorted order.

```
# this is a little more precise than the cat | grep | sed hackery
extract_key() {
  gawk -F'[[:space:]]' -v key="\"$1\"" '
    BEGIN { FPAT = "\"([^\"]+)\""; }
    $1 == key {
      if (substr($2, 1, 1) == "\"") {
        $2 = substr($2, 2, length($2) - 2)
      }
      print $2
      exit(0)
    }
    END { exit(1); }
  '
}

die() { echo "$*" >&2; exit 1; }

build_gamemenu() {
  declare -g -A game_ids=( )  # declare -A makes our array associative
  local f name id             # this way we don't pollute global namespace
  for f in ~/.steam/steam/steamapps/*.acf; do
    name=$(extract_key name <"$f") || die "Could not find name for $f"
    id=$(extract_key appid <"$f") || die "Could not find id for $f"
    game_ids[$name]=$id
  done
}

# note that readarray -d is only available in very new bash releases
# for older releases, instead you can use:
# sorted_names=( ); while IFS= read -r name; do sorted_names+=( "$name" ); done < <(...)
readarray -d '' sorted_names < <(printf '%s\0' "${!game_ids[@]}" | sort -z)
build_gamemenu
```

To then print our games ordered by name:

```
for game_name in "${sorted_names[@]}"; do
  game_id=${game_ids[$game_name]}
  echo "$game_name [$game_id]"
done
```

...or, to generate a single array to pass to whiptail:

```
whiptail_args=( )
for game_name in "${sorted_names[@]}"; do
  game_id=${game_ids[$game_name]}
  whiptail_args+=( "$game_id" "$game_name" )
done
```